# Cubase Elements 7 signal routing

Tags: cubase, audio-interfaces

My soundcard is a DMX 6 Terratec. It has 6 out ports in the back. I have two stereo out channels and I am trying to send click to one and the rest to the other.

However, both hardware ports are sending the same mix even though I setup stereo 1 as the mix for the music and stereo 2 for click track.

Comment: have you tried to use the soundcard software mixer? does it allow the routing of signals to different outputs? and does cubase elements allow multichannel outputs or just stereo?

Comment: I suspect that my soundcard is most likely broken...i tried a different one and it worked fine.